# How to create a custom object from an array value

Tags: powershell

The purpose of my code is to pull information from network cards on Windows hosts.

Unless I am mistaken, there is no built-in way of doing this. So what I want to do is to build a custom object.

The problem I am facing is that there are mutiple cards on different systems and I am not able to output the information in a human readable format for each property is an array.

```
$AdapterSpeed = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | foreach-object {Get-WmiObject -namespace root/WMI -class MSNdis_LinkSpeed -filter "InstanceName='$($_.Name)'"} | Select-Object InstanceName,NdisLinkSpeed,Active)

$AdpaterProp = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName . | Select-Object -Property Description,DHCPEnabled,DHCPServer,DNSDomain,DNSServerSearchOrder,DefaultIPGateway)

# How can I create an array of propertie
$myCustomObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    'Description' = $AdpaterProp.Description
    'Speed' = $AdapterSpeed.NdisLinkSpeed
    'DHCPEnabled' = $AdpaterProp.DHCPEnabled
    'DHCPServer'= $AdpaterProp.DHCPServer
    'DNSDomain'= $AdpaterProp.DNSDomain
    'DNSServerSearchOrder'= $AdpaterProp.DNSServerSearchOrder
    'DefaultIPGateway'= $AdpaterProp.DefaultIPGateway
}
```

What I would like to see is something like this:

Description: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 
DHCPEnabled          : True 
DHCPServer           : 10.0.0.20 
DNSDomain            : localhost.localdomain 
DNSServerSearchOrder : {10.0.0.11, 10.0.0.12} 
DefaultIPGateway     : {10.0.0.1} 
NdisLinkSpeed        : 100000000 
Active               : True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this in a single loop so that you can keep track of which `MSNdis_LinkSpeed` and `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` instances are tied to which adaptor:

```
$allCustomObjects = foreach($adapter in Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter){
    $AdapterSpeed = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class MSNdis_LinkSpeed -Filter "InstanceName='$($adapter.Name)'"
    $AdpaterProp  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Index='$($adapter.Index)'"
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        'Description' = $AdpaterProp.Description
        'Speed' = $AdapterSpeed.NdisLinkSpeed
        'DHCPEnabled' = $AdpaterProp.DHCPEnabled
        'DHCPServer'= $AdpaterProp.DHCPServer
        'DNSDomain'= $AdpaterProp.DNSDomain
        'DNSServerSearchOrder'= $AdpaterProp.DNSServerSearchOrder
        'DefaultIPGateway'= $AdpaterProp.DefaultIPGateway
    }
}
```

`$allCustomObjects` now contains multiple custom object, one for each `Win32_NetworkAdapter` instance on your machine